# Rails: When Escape Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

My question is if ruby code inside script tag MUST be always escaped?
Have I to escape javascript when I set a class/id of a div for example?

```
<script>
    $("#button_<%= comment.id %>").click(function(){
       ... ...
       ... ...
    });
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
    $("#button_<%= escape_javascript comment.id.to_s %>").click(function(){
       ... ...
       ... ...
    });
</script>
```

Or ruby code must be escaped only when render partials? Thank you

Comment: No need to escape the content you are sure about. `"#button_<%= comment.id %>"` is perfectly fine, since `comment.id` is definitely integer.

Comment: Ok thank you. So I only have to escape string. This example need to be escaped ?
$("#post-title").html("<%= escape_javascript @post.title) %>");